# How to remove specific elements with linkedStack

Tags: java, stack

I'm using stack to do the coding. I'm trying to remove 1 specific record based on the ID. But when I try to delete, it will remove all the record with the use of clear(). Is there any other way to solve this?

This is all the record.

[image]

This is the record after I try to delete.

[image]

This is my delete specific record function. below is the stack.clear() function.

```
 private static Singer DeleteSpecificSinger(int id){
    for(Singer singer: singerList){
        if(singer.getId()==id){
           singerList.clear();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

  public void clear() {
    topNode=null;
}
```

Comment: I don't know what is a linkedStack, but shouldn't you clear / delete specific element from singerList - do it on singer instead of singerList?

Comment: its is based on stack. I'm trying to set the integer ID to null to remove the record but can't  due to null cannot convert to int. Is there any solution?

Comment: You should edit your question to reflect this latest comment because "is there any other way to do it" isn't really a useful question. There are all sorts of ways to do anything, but you obviously have some specific problem to solve, so why not just ask about that? You should also add your implementation of the clear method -- I have no idea what's going on under the covers there. Finally, take inspiration from LinkedList implementations which remove nodes by dereferencing them in the previous and following nodes.

Comment: I dont even know if what you have will work at all because it should throw a ConcurrentModificationException

Comment: Is this your own stack class or a java.util class?